# I am getting an error while building grade file

Tags: android

I am trying to build my gradle after adding the following lines

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${versions.supportLib}"

    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${versions.supportLib}"

    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:${versions.supportLib}"

    implementation "com.android.support:design:${versions.supportLib}"
```

I get the following error

```
Error:(32, 0) Could not get unknown property 'versions' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Sagar\Desktop\SickLab\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

My entire grade file is as follows

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sagar.sicklab"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    implementation("com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.1@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }


    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${versions.supportLib}"

    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${versions.supportLib}"

    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:${versions.supportLib}"

    implementation "com.android.support:design:${versions.supportLib}"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


    compile 'com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.2'
    compile 'eu.long1:spacetablayout:1.0.4'


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you haven't defined a objected named "versions" that gradle can access. The error message says that it couldn't find it.

> Could not get unknown property 'versions' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

You need to define an object named versions that has a variable called "supportLib" and holds the value of the support library you want to use.

I'm never done this before, so it maybe be completely wrong, but here is some pseudocode that may help you define your object:

```
version = new Version(supportLib: "26.1.0")

class Version {
    String supportLib

    String toString() {
        supportLib
    }
}
```

You define this in you same build.gradle file. What will happen when gradle is executed, it will instantiate the versions object and read the version string value from the supportLib field and append it to the support library String. With that being said, I've never seen the "implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${versions.supportLib}" syntax before so you definitely will need to experiment. [Here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/09/gradle-goodness-using-objects-for.html) is the website that gave me the pseudocode.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i was actually trying to implement this library for navigation drawer in my app.  https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer  . Ill take a look at what u said

Comment: I looked at the project and if you look at the same project they create a versions object that contains a supportLib string that holds the value of the support library they want to use in the app. Here is link to exactly what you need to do to use it. https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/03ad99bad3f53e53656e11abe8d6b8903c45d077/build.gradle#L10 
Just copy the line from that build.gradle file and replace the string to use the version you actually want to use and then add it to your top level build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your file:

```
ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = "25.3.1"
}
```

And replace:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
```